# iOS - What is the difference between Table View and Table View Controller

Tags: ios, uikit, uitableview

In the Object Library of Xcode, there are two options one can use to create table view - table view and table view controller. 
What is the difference between the two and when would they be used ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A TableViewController is a ViewController with a TableView built in.  This will have the delegate methods needed already declared and setup.  This VC is already a TableView delegate and datasource.  It cannot be resized.  Upside is ease of use, downside is very limited flexibility.

A TableView is just that a TableView (subclass of UIView).  It can be added to a ViewController and resized, used alongside another view based object, etc.  The upside is the flexibility, the downside is that you have to setup the delegate and datasource methods yourself (in my opinion, well worth the time to get the flexibility).

One other note is that when using the new Static TableView cells (part of iOS5), you have to use a TableViewController.

Comment: Good point in mentioning the lack of resizing / sharing the `UITableView` with other controls on the same screen when using a `UITableViewController`. Well, on the other hand, one could always use the `tableHeaderView` and the `tableFooterView` part for other controls.

Comment: True, but when doing stuff like having a static SearchBar (that doesn't scroll), a VC with a TableView works well.

Answer (score 6):

The `UITableViewController` is a subclass of the `UIViewController`. It already assumes you will have `UITableView` as your rootView, so you already have access from the code to a tableView (self.tableView). It implements the `UITableViewDataSource` and the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol. It also gives you alot of methods for you to override. It allows you to not depend on XIB file, because you already know what you will have (`UITableView` as a rootView).

The `UITableView` is just `UIView`, normally you will have to comply to the protocols I have referenced above in your `UIViewController` in order to populate (data source) and work with it (delegate), and you probably have to create an IBOutlet for your `UITableView`.

On one hand you have speed but you are not as flexible as the other path. On the other you have the opposite.

Comment: Your answer is generally correct but a little IB centric for my taste. Just to clarify, IBOutlets certainly are only needed in case you intend to use the InterfaceBuilder for laying out your views. That task can certainly just as well (sometimes better) be accomplished using plain code.

Comment: I do prefer to use `InterfaceBuilder` whenever I can, its faster and it keeps the code clean. Of course you can declare an `UITableView` in your code and just add it your `UIView`, although I don't like it.